# How to __forceinline a function for VS2008?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I need to "force inline" the following method in the C++ project that is compiled in Visual Studio 2008 (MFC project):

```
//.h file
__forceinline static BOOL IsLicenseGood(LIC_NAME_NUMBER& lnn);
```

and

```
//.cpp file
__forceinline BOOL CMyClass::IsLicenseGood(LIC_NAME_NUMBER& lnn)
{
    //Do checks
    ...
    return result;
}
```

But when I compile it for `release` build, it gives me the following repeating warnings:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xmemory(154) : warning C4506: no definition for inline function 'BOOL CMyClass::IsLicenseGood(LIC_NAME_NUMBER &)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\vector(46) : warning C4506: no definition for inline function 'BOOL CMyClass::IsLicenseGood(LIC_NAME_NUMBER &)'
```

Any idea what is the issue there?

Comment: unless you plan on moving the implementation to your header, using `__forceinline` is nonsense. You don't force-inline a declaration; you force-inline a *definition*, and said-definition should be available for inlining by the translation unit that will be using it. Yours is buried in a cpp file.

Comment: If your license checking code is anything other than trivial, then it is unlikely that `__forceinline` will have any effect. The name is a misnomer: it doesn't actually force anything, it is just a stronger hint to the compiler than `__inline`. A trivial function that is a candidate for inlining will get inlined regardless of annotations. A non-trivial function that shouldn't be inlined won't get inlined, no matter how much you try to `force` it. The compiler will just ignore the annotation and move along. And inlining a license check won't make your app more crack-proof. One JMP beats it.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Good point. So if I moved my implementation to a header file, do I still need `__forceinline` to have it inlined?

Comment: @CodyGray: Inlining license checking does make the crack more tedious, because now it isn't just **one** JMP, but as many as there are inlined instantiations of the license checking code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for inlining to work.

The "classic" way is that the compiler, during translation from source to machine-code (exactly where in this is not well defined, and differnet compiler vendors probably do this slightly differently). This method REQUIRES that the source code is avialable for the function to be inlined - otherwise, how can the compiler inline it? So for this to work in general, the function must either be used ONLY in one source file (and thuse don't need to be declared in any header file), or the function can be used in several places, as long as it's defined in a header file that is included by the calling code.

In your case, the compiler is complaining that it can't do this, because only the declaration is available in the header-file, not the definition - so the compiler says "but how do you expect me to do what you've asked, without telling me WHAT to inline".

The "new" way is called "Link Time Optimisation" or "Whole Program Optimisation" (depending on which compiler you are talking about). This works by only partially compiling the source files into some intermediate representation of your source - not source code, but not actual machine-code either, it's some kind of level between those, which has more information about "what the code is about". When the final executable is then linked together, the machine code is generated. At this stage, the inlining process is also performed, and this means that suitable functions can be inlined even if the compiler couldn't see that function during compilation.

This allows inlining in from "anywhere", but requires a different setup for the linker options. I expect the `forceinline` will still be warned for, since the compiler at that point doesn't know whether you are inlining early or late - although I'm not 100% sure of that.

The SIMPLE answer to your problem is to move the definition (function body) to the header file, and be done with it. Or remove the `forceinline` keyword.

Comment: OK, it's a general info on compilation & linking. Thanks. But in my case I'm using `VS2008` C++ compiler. Although your answer brought up a follow-up question. How do I know that my function was actually inlined in the resulting `release` built?

Comment: By enabling warnings for "functions not inlined", perhaps? I'm not an expert on that paritcular compiler, so not sure if there is one - I seem to remember the version I used has one. Or by inspecting the machine code generated. Of course, the reason you are inlining this function specifically, I expect is that you have done performance measurements and thus found that the function needs to be inlined...

Comment: No. The reason for inlining is to make reverse engineering of the license code more difficult. As for inspecting a machine code to know if function was inlined, it's quite a daunting task for a `release` build, isn't it?

Comment: So you don't think someone will be able to discover what your algorithm is, because it's copied in 200 places instead of a single place? "Complexity is not security", you know...

Comment: So, in other words, you're doing this only to make your software take up more RAM and diskspace? Great!

Comment: For just a little bit of work I can make it significantly more difficult to reverse engineer (or crack) my licensing code. Note that I don't say that it improves security. Security has nothing to do with what I'm after. And yes, it'd probably add about 40K to the executable image. Quite a good trade-off in my view.

Comment: But it's not significantly harder to crack, since it's just the same code duplicated a large number of times, so a bit of patternmatching in the code and you'd be figured out. Yes, it's more TEDIOUS, but if your application is actually worth cracking in that way, then someone will figure out how to, and write a bit of code to replace your license check with "return true".

Comment: Have you ever done machine code/asm debugging? I posted a screenshot of how disassembled code looks like. So take a look I don't think you can resolve it just by "pattern matching" or "returning true". Otherwise, yes, some determined hacker can crack anything. In this case I'm just matching "his" efforts to do it with mine (force-inlining it.) And there's no match in complexity there.

Comment: Yes, lots of machine code debugging. I grew up with basically ONLY that, since source code debuggers didn't really work (assuming there was a debugger AT ALL, on many machines, you had to rely on code inspection, etc). I have also bypassed various license systems - it usually just takes changing one instruction to always jump to "success" instead of conditionally on "did I get what I wanted".

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and I was able to accomplish what I wanted with as little changes as possible. I need to note that I tested it **only** with Visual Studio 2008 C++ compiler, so I'm not sure if it's going to work with other compilers. So here are the steps to inline a function:

1. Move the entire function to the declaration `.h` file. It totally broke a nice layout of my function declarations in the `.h` file, but ... oh well.
2. Still use the `__forceinline` directive. My tests showed that for a small function placed into the `.h` file, it is inlined automatically. More complex functions, are not. Luckily, Microsoft's compiler seems to "honor" `__forceinline` directive and inlines larger functions too.

So the function would look like this:

```
//.h file
static __forceinline BOOL IsLicenseNumberGood(LIC_NAME_NUMBER& lnn)
{
    //Place the entire function code into .h file here
    ...
    return result;
}
```

---

Now the second question that came up while I was working on this, is *how to know that your function was actually inlined?* Evidently there's no built-in way of checking it. So I came up with the following steps. So feel free to correct me if you know a better way?

- Obviously build a `Release` project (because `Debug` configuration will not be inlined.)
- Add some test markers to differentiate the resulting machine code around the function in question. I was building a 32-bit module, so I could still use the `asm` directive to add some inline assembly. I chose that because it is easy to add some harmless machine code that would not be added by a compiler otherwise. (If you work with 64-bit code, then you'll have to do something else. Maybe use some distinctive API call, like [GdiFlush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144844(v=vs.85).aspx) that doesn't change anything.)
- Lastly when done testing, remove assembly markers.

So here's a snapshot of the method in C++ view:

[image]

After you build it for `Release` configuration set a break-point on a method that you need to check inlining for and start debugging (or hit F5.)

When the break-point triggers, switch to disassembly view (or hit Alt+8). You should see the opening triple asm commands:

[image]

Then if the function was successfully inlined you see a large solid chunk of assembler code without inclusion of the C++ code. This will be your inlined function's machine code. You can step into it and follow the asm logic, if you know it to double-check.

In my case, the inlined method ends almost 1K bytes later with a closing triple asm commands that I added at the end:

[image]

So this seemed to have worked for me. It's a totally manual method, but it works.

Thanks everyone who contributed!

Comment: *"Move the entire function to the declaration .h file. It totally broke a nice layout of my function declarations in the .h file"* - Why? Can't you just keep all your declarations together, and provide the definition after all other declarations? The compiler needs the definition at the place of invocation. It doesn't care whether the declaration and definition are the same.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, of course I can. It's just a small "price" to pay.